# How to use a looping to split the data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops

I did this code on Matlab, but I'd like to know if there's an easier way to do it.

```
i=1.4
j=1.5
k=1.6
l=1.7
        
ind1 = find(event>=i)
ind2 = find(event>=j)
ind3 = find(event>=k)
ind4 = find(event>=l)
    
b1 = dd (ind1)   %dd is date 'dd/mm/yyyy'
b2 = dd (ind2)
b3 = dd (ind3)
b4 = dd (ind4) 

figure
bins=6
histogram(b1.Month, bins)
hold on
histogram(b2.Month, bins)
histogram(b3.Month, bins)
histogram(b4.Month, bins)
```

I have a 3274x2 size data (1st column is date and 2nd is event) and what I'm trying to do is to split the data according to the events and their correspondent date. So, I would like to get the data: e.g., for events >= 1.4, for events >=1.5...and so on until 2.3. After that, I need to plot the date in the histogram.
It works with the code above, but I was trying to do it in a looping. That's my attempt (it doesn't do what I want):

```
for n=1.4:0.1:2.3
    
   indices = find(event>=n)
   c = [event(indices)] 
   d = [dd(indices)]          %dd is date 'dd/mm/yyyy'
   
end

figure
bins=6
histogram(d.Month, bins)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your loop attempt won't work, cause your variable `d` will be overwritten with each iteration. You could set a counter which increases by 1 after each iteration: `counter = counter + 1; d(counter) = dd(indices);`. By the way, even if I don't know your data I think, you don't need `find`, it should be enough to just use `b1 = dd(events>=i);`. On top of that could also avoid the loop by using `arrayfun` and reduce many lines in your code.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use a counter before, as you said, but it doesn't work. I got the error: Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the
right side.

Comment: Hm yeah because `dd(indices)` has a different size with each iteration. In that case I'd suggest you to work with a cell array: `d{counter} = dd(indices);`. If you never worked with cell arrays, it might be a bit confusing for you in the beginning and also `histogram(d.Month)` won't work. But you can use `cellfun` to apply a function to each cell of those arrays.

Comment: `d{counter} = dd(indices)` this one works. Sorry, but I never used `cellfun` before...so now if I want the histogram works, should I call 'histogram' inside the cellfun?  Something like this: `cellfun(histogram, d{counter})` ?

Comment: You're almost there. To understand `cellfun` I also needed some practice. You call it after the loop: `cellfun(@histogram,d)` should do it. If you also want to specify your `bins`, you need to create another cell array for that with the length as amount of cells in `d`. I can give you the whole answer, but I don't know if you want to plot all your data in one histogram and if the data in `dd` are just `string` or actually a `struct`, cause you call them with `d.Month`.

Comment: Yes, I want to plot all of it in one figure (one histogram above the other and so on) and specify the bins. I tried the `cellfun(@histogram,d)` but it gave me just the last histogram, I need to specify like this `cellfun(@histogram, d(:,1))`  to work. The data in dd is a datetime array (dd/mm/yyyy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your data in dd is a datetime array and you want to plot all in one histogram:

```
counter = 1;
bins=6
for n=1.4:0.1:2.3
     
   c{counter} = event(event>=n); 
   d{counter} = dd(event>=n);          %dd is date 'dd/mm/yyyy'   
   histogram(d{counter},bins)          %OR histogram(d{counter}.Month,bins)
   hold on
   counter = counter + 1;

end
```

You don't even need to assign the values to c and d, so the only thing you'd have to do inside the loop is this:
`histogram(dd(event>=n),bins);`

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much for your time!